# useState keeps getting reset to initialValue on re render

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

So my code for the screen looks something like this. I have a useState `amount` that keeps getting reset to initialValue on re-renders. I have around 3 useEffects. One of them is in the sample code here where I am getting the amount from db and setting it using setAmount.

```js
    const ConfirmPaymentDialog = props => {
       const getInitialVal = () => {
          console.log('Initial Amount: 0');
          return conversions.numberToBigNumber(0);
       };
       const [amount, setAmount] = useState<BigNumber>(getInitialVal());
    
       useEffect(() => {
           getAmountToPay();
       },[]);
    
       const getAmountToPay = async () => {
        const amount = await myDbModule.getAmount(customer.id);
        console.log('DB Amount: ' + amount?.toString());
        setAmount(amount || conversions.numberToBigNumber(0));
      };
    
       useEffect(() => {
       ...
       }, [isInputTextFocused])
    
      console.log('Rendering');
      return (<View>...</View>);
    }
```

When I open this screen.I get following console logs

```
 LOG  Initial Amount: 0
 LOG  Rendering
 LOG  DB Amount: 500
 LOG  Initial Amount: 0
 LOG  Rendering
 LOG  Initial Amount: 0
 LOG  Rendering
 LOG  Initial Amount: 0
 LOG  Rendering
 LOG  Initial Amount: 0
 LOG  Rendering
 LOG  Initial Amount: 0
 LOG  Rendering
```

How do I stop my useState from resetting back to default value on re-renders

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not actually resetted to the initial value. You just keep calling the function that generates the initial value.

Instead of calling it, pass it as callback (see [lazy initial state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state)) to the `useState()` hook, and it will be called once:

```
const [amount, setAmount] = useState<BigNumber>(getInitialVal); // getInitialVal instead of getInitialVal()
```

Comment: I actually added this function to add console log. But even if I use `useState(conversions.numberToBigNumber(0))`. The behaviour is same.

Comment: Don't call the function directly in initial state - use `useState(() => conversions.numberToBigNumber(0))`

Comment: Ok then i was debugging this the wrong way. This clears many things.  Thanks