# Facing problem with extra re-render and resetting value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```js
interface TimerProp {
  initialTime: number;
  handleAgentToast: (type: string) => void;
}
interface AgentToast {
  toastData?: ToastData;
  handleAgentToast: (type: string) => void;
}
interface AgentToastHandler {
  toastData?: ToastData;
}
const Timer = (props: TimerProp) => {
  const { initialTime, handleAgentToast } = props;
  const [time, setTime] = useState(initialTime);
  const { minutes, seconds } = formatTimeInHHMMSS(time);
  useEffect(() => {
    let intervalId: NodeJS.Timeout;
    if (time > 0) {
      intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        setTime(prevTime => prevTime - 1);
      }, 1000);
    } else {
      handleAgentToast(HeartbeatToastType.AGENT_MARKED_INACTIVE);
    }

    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, [time]);

  return (
    <>
      <Typography variant="p3" className={styles.timer}>{`${padNumber(minutes)}:${padNumber(
        seconds,
      )}`}</Typography>
      <Typography variant="p3" color="var(--blue-dark)">
        secs
      </Typography>
    </>
  );
};
export const handleForceOnline = async (handleAgentToast: any) => {
  try {
    const url = getRxApiUrl(ApiKeys.FORCE_ONLINE);
    await ApiHelper({ url, method: 'POST' });
    handleAgentToast(HeartbeatToastType.AGENT_MARKED_ACTIVE);
  } catch (error) {
    handleAgentToast(HeartbeatToastType.MARK_ACTIVE_FAILURE);
  }
};
const AgentToast = (props: AgentToast) => {
  const { toastData, handleAgentToast } = props;
  const handleSwitch = () => {
    handleForceOnline(handleAgentToast);
  };
  return (
    <Card className={styles.card}>
      <div className={styles.cardHeader}>
        <img src={errorIcon} alt="errorIcon" />
        <Typography variant="h3" className={styles.agentUnavailableMessage}>
          Agent unavailable!
        </Typography>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.timerInfo}>
        <Typography variant="p3">System marking you as inactive in </Typography>
        {toastData?.timeOut && (
          <Timer initialTime={toastData.timeOut} handleAgentToast={handleAgentToast} />
        )}
      </div>
      <div className={styles.statusToggler}>
        <Typography variant="p3">Keep me as active</Typography>
        <Switch onChange={handleSwitch} />
      </div>
    </Card>
  );
};
export const AgentToastHandler = ({ toastData }: AgentToastHandler) => {
  const [agentToastType, setAgentToastType] = useState(toastData?.toastType);
  switch (agentToastType) {
    case HeartbeatToastType.AGENT_MARKED_ACTIVE:
      return <AgentMarkedActiveToast />;
    case HeartbeatToastType.AGENT_MARKED_INACTIVE:
      return <AgentMarkedInactiveToast />;
    case HeartbeatToastType.MARK_ACTIVE_FAILURE:
      return <AgentFailureToast />;
    default:
      return <AgentToast toastData={toastData} handleAgentToast={setAgentToastType} />;
  }
};
```

I have this component, I am rendering AgentToastHandler to render toast, in the initial toast  I have a toggle button, through which I'm changing the state and rendering other component. Problem is on toggle as per handleForceOnline I'm changing states, but somehow a re-render is again getting triggered and causing state to be '' again. But for the case when the timer is getting complete and I'm again setting state it is working fine. Also on commenting `await ApiHelper({ url, method: 'POST' });` also makes it work alright.

I tried disabling strict mode but it didn't work, can someone please help?

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60903691/usestate-keeps-getting-reset-to-initialvalue-on-re-render) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69717405/initial-values-in-usestate-not-updated-after-re-render?rq=3) but it didn't help.